# Как заставить Pycharm воспринимать файл как шаблон Django?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-template

Есть файл с расширением **xml** (Это будет кастомный sitemap для сайта).

В нём есть некоторая логика, требующая работу шаблонизатора.

Соответственно, хотелось бы, чтобы **Pycharm** использовал подсветку синтаксиса и автозавершение для шаблонов *django*.

По умолчанию он так не делает для данного файла.

Можно ли его заставить?

Рассматривается вариант в том числе изменения расширения файла, всё равно через urls можно любой путь сделать... Но естественно, это не *html*.

Comment: вы хотите чтобы PyCharm понимал синтаксис Html для Джанги?

Comment: @E1mir при чем тут html? Не понял Вашего вопроса. Шаблонизатор это шаблонизатор, ему всё равно какого формата файл, хоть html, хоть json ... Он видит свои магические {} и работает с ними... Суть вопроса изложена выше.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич а pycharm какой версии? community или professional?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров   professional

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич в этом случае ответ - не знаю, а в случае с комьюнити ответ был бы - никак :)

Comment: Я уже и без этого сделал. Но с подсветкой синтаксиса было бы покрасивее и немного проще :)

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206592245-Pycharm-not-recognizing-django-template-tags

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/templates.html

Comment: @Victor судя по всему всё должно работать и так, но почему то не сработало. В саппорт JetBrains по данному поводу лениво писать.

Comment: Ну попробуй переустановить :)